# Is a perfectly normal space always a paracompact space?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is a perfectly normal space always a paracompact space?

A topological space $X$ is called a perfectly normal space if $X$ is a normal space and every closed subset of $X$ is a $G_\delta$-set.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Problem 5.5.3 in Engelking's _General Topology_ is about the construction of a perfectly normal non-paracompact space (and the demonstrations of these facts).

Comment: Also, see [Dan Ma's Topology Blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/a-subspace-of-bings-example-g/).  (Recall that every paracompact space is collectionwise normal.)

Comment: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm78/fm78129.pdf is a consistent counterexample with online description available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some counterexamples:

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm97/fm9714.pdf

http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/a-subspace-of-bings-example-g/

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm78/fm78129.pdf (consistent example)

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-118-03/S0002-9939-1993-1137225-2/S0002-9939-1993-1137225-2.pdf; Ostaszewski spaces are all very beautiful examples, as they are hereditarily separable, perfectly normal, locally compact but not Lindelöf and a paracompact separable space is Lindelöf. Of course we need $\diamondsuit$ but we do need some axiom for such a nice space:

An interesting consistency result: it is consistent that all locally compact perfectly normal spaces are paracompact: http://www.math.toronto.edu/tall/publications/LT.pdf