# Is every perfectly normal space submetrizable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420783/is-a-perfectly-normal-space-always-a-paracompact-space), Some counterexamples are given which shows shat not every perfectly normal space is paracompact. Thanks Henno. I have another question. It may be difficult:

**Is every perfectly normal space submetrizable?**

> A topological space $X$ is called a perfectly normal space if $X$ is a normal space and every closed subset of $X$ is a $G_\delta$-set.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Alexandroff's double arrow space (or [the split interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval)), i.e. $[0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ ordered lexicographically, in the order topology) is compact Hausdorff (so normal), hereditarily Lindelöf (which is equivalent to all closed sets being $G_\delta$ for compact spaces) but not metrisable. Hence it is not submetrisable (it would have a $G_\delta$ diagonal otherwise, and a (countably) compact space with a $G_\delta$ diagonal is metrisable).

Comment: Better argument: a compact Hausdorff non-metrisable space is never submetrisable, as it cannot have a weaker Hausdorff topology that is not homeomorphic (standard fact).